# Fastest way to obtain a greyscaled bitmap from Android Camera (Preview)

Tags: android, camera, preview, yuv, grayscale

i have a performance issue. Im currently working on a realtime app, which needs to process camera images in like 10 frames per second.
It turns out that my bottleneck is currently the conversion to greyscale (80 to 150 ms).
 And by the way I need in fact a greyscale integer Array (one int for one pixel). So probably the saturation method, does not work for me, but i'm not completly sure about that.

What i'm currently doing:

-Optain YUV Data from the camera preview in the

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
```

-Convert YUV to colored Bitmap and greyscale array

```
static public void decodeYUV(int[] out,int[] outGrey,  byte[] fg, int width, int height)
        throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
        int sz = width * height;
        if (out == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("buffer out is null");
        if (out.length < sz)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer out size " + out.length
                + " < minimum " + sz);
        if (fg == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("buffer 'fg' is null");
        if (fg.length < sz)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer fg size " + fg.length
                + " < minimum " + sz * 3 / 2);
        int i, j;
        int Y, Cr = 0, Cb = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int pixPtr = j * width;
        final int jDiv2 = j >> 1;
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Y = fg[pixPtr];
            if (Y < 0)
                Y += 255;
            if ((i & 0x1) != 1) {
                final int cOff = sz + jDiv2 * width + (i >> 1) * 2;
                Cb = fg[cOff];
                if (Cb < 0)
                    Cb += 127;
                else
                    Cb -= 128;
                Cr = fg[cOff + 1];
                if (Cr < 0)
                    Cr += 127;
                else
                    Cr -= 128;
            }
            int R = Y + Cr + (Cr >> 2) + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 5);
            if (R < 0)
                R = 0;
            else if (R > 255)
                R = 255;
            int G = Y - (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 4) + (Cb >> 5) - (Cr >> 1)
                    + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 4) + (Cr >> 5);
            if (G < 0)
                G = 0;
            else if (G > 255)
                G = 255;
            int B = Y + Cb + (Cb >> 1) + (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 6);
            if (B < 0)
                B = 0;
            else if (B > 255)
                B = 255;
            out[pixPtr] = 0xff000000 + (B << 16) + (G << 8) + R;
            outGrey[pixPtr] = (int)(B*0.114f + R*0.299f + G*0.587f);
            pixPtr++;
        }
        }
        }
```

Is there a faster way to get to this point?

OpenCV?
Actual Camera Picture Capturing to let the OS do the work?

My next move would be to thread the YUV decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static public void decodeYUV(int[] outGrey,  byte[] fg, int width, int height) {
    int sz = width * height;
    for (int pixPtr = 0; pixPtr < sz; pixPtr++) {
        outGrey[pixPtr] = fg[pixPtr] & 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, i assume that this is the way to optain the grey values directly from yuv. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean instant filter effect on camera preview? You could considerate [android-gpuimage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) project on github. Your only task is writing corresponding shader script which could achieve your filter effect.